# Python Pivot for multiple entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot

I have a repeating list of Employe Name-Skill-Value pairs sourced from pivoted excel data. I loaded the data into a data frame, Staff, that looks like so:

```
Name  Skill Attribute  Value 
 Bob S  Certification    ACA
 Bob S  Certification    GSA
 Bob S  Degree           Comp Sci
 Kate    Certification    BCA
```

I now want to pivot the data back, in python, so that it’s

```
Name  Certification  Degree
Bob S  ACA              Comp Sci
Bob S  GSA              Lit
Kate    BCA              None
```

When I try pivoting in python with:

```
Staff=Staff.drop_duplicates([‘Name’,’Skill Attribute’])
 Staff=Staff.pivot(‘Name’, ‘Skill Attribute’, ‘Value)
```

I lose value data. For example, Bob S has two certifications, but only one shows:

```
    Name  Certification  Degree
    Bob S  ACA              Comp Sci
    Kate    BCA              None
```

Attempting to use the pivot function without the preceding drop_duplicates line gives a “ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape”

How can I pivot so that all value data is kept, and multiple skills attribute-value entries per employee name are allowed?

Comment: how would I (or a program) know which degree to assign to a certificate? Why Bob's `ACA` is a `Comp Sci`, while `GSA` is `Lit`?

Comment: Degrees aren’t assigned to certificates. Degrees and certificates are independent values that are attributes descriptive of an employee. It’s employee data that I’m trying to display in the pivoted format. For example, an employee has an SSN and a birth date, both of which are stored, but which aren’t themselves related. They’re independent attributes of the employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.set_index(
    ['Name', df.groupby(['Name', 'Skill Attribute']).cumcount(), 'Skill Attribute']
).Value.unstack().reset_index('Name').rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index(drop=True)

    Name Certification    Degree
0  Bob S           ACA  Comp Sci
1  Bob S           GSA      None
2   Kate           BCA      None
```